# applescript droplet: Add a suffix to filename

Tags: applescript, file-rename, suffix

I just discovered Applescript and started using its potential. I've been researching for a solution for this for 2 days but nothing worked!.. Here is an applescript droplet that processes the deposited jpg files in a folder through a program and then moves the resulting files to a new subfolder. I'm new to programming and my skills are very limited. I was trying to add a suffix to the final processed file, but there's no way I could! This is the code.

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
set project to (this_folder as text) & "processor.imprc" -- This is the name  of the file that calls the external application

set done_folder to "Done"
tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists folder done_folder of this_folder) then
            make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:done_folder}
        end if
        set the destination_folder to folder done_folder of this_folder as alias
    set the destination_directory to POSIX path of the destination_folder
end tell
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in these_items
        set this_item to item i of these_items
        set the item_info to info for this_item
        if this_item is not the destination_folder and the name extension of the item_info is "jpg" then
            set the item_path to the POSIX path of this_item
            set the destination_path to the destination_directory & (name of the item_info) -- Here is where I think it defines the name of the "produced" file

tell application "Image Process"  -- From this point on commands for the external application start
            activate
            open project
            tell first document
                set source to item_path
                impose in destination_path
                close saving no
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

I'd much appreciate any help to add the suffix ("_edited" for example) to each processed file (in "Done" folder)

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your requirements are more clear. To do this, we need 2 scripts in folder actions :

The first script is attached to folder A. It checks if folder done exists and, if not, it creates Done folder, attaching also a new folder action called Done_Action.

Then this script can pick every file dropped in A, and send it to your image process application.

The second script is the one which will be the folder action of folder Done.
It processes each file added in Done folder (from your image process application) to change its name, adding the suffix "_edited".

To make full process operational, you must do the following:

1) Add, in the first script bellow, your instructions about your process image application (I did not because I can't test this !)

2) save this script in your Folder Action scripts (name does not matter) and attached your parent folder (A) to this script :

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
set project to (this_folder as text) & "processor.imprc" -- This is the name  of the file that calls the external application
set Done_Folder to "Done"
set Done_Script to "Done_Action.scpt"

-- this part creates Done folder if not exist and attached new folder action script Done_Script to Done folder.
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder Done_Folder of this_folder) then
        make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:Done_Folder}
        tell application "System Events"
            make new folder action at end of folder actions with properties {enabled:true, name:Done_Script, path:(this_folder as string) & Done_Folder}
            tell folder action Done_Script to make new script at end of scripts with properties {name:Done_Script}
        end tell
    end if
    set the destination_folder to folder Done_Folder of this_folder as alias
    set the destination_directory to POSIX path of the destination_folder
end tell

repeat This_item in these_items times -- loop on each added item in parent folder
    set the item_info to info for This_item
    if This_item is not the destination_folder and the name extension of the item_info is "jpg" then
        set the item_path to the POSIX path of This_item
        set the destination_path to the destination_directory & (name of the item_info)

        -- add here your Image Process script (I can't test it !) 

    end if
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

As you can see, when the folder Done is created, the script attaches to it the folder action with script 'Done_Action.scpt'.

3) save this second script bellow into you folder action script with the name 'Done_Action.Scpt' (it must be same as name used in first script)

```
-- this script is trigger when file is added into the done folder
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
set Sufix to "_edited"

repeat with This_Item in these_items
    tell application "Finder"
        set Ext to name extension of This_Item
        set FileName to name of This_Item
        if (offset of Sufix in FileName) = 0 then
            set NameOnly to text 1 thru ((offset of Ext in FileName) - 2) of FileName -- get name without .extension
            set name of This_Item to (NameOnly & Sufix & "." & Ext) -- change the name of the file
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

During my test, I have been in trouble, because each time I was changing the file name in the done folder, the script was run again.

I think this is a bug from Apple on El Captain (I did not had that issue on Snow Leopard). To work around that, I added a test before changing the file name, to check if name already contains the sufix '_edited'. if it does, then I skip.

The consequence is that your files should never contains '_edited' before you drop them in parent folder A !

All tested and OK (except still the image process itself).

Answer (score 0):

The script below adds the suffix to your selected file. It must be added just after your tell "Image Process" bloc, and before the end repeat.

```
set This_item to choose file -- to be delete, this is just to test this script alone
set Sufix to "_edited"

tell application "Finder"
set Ext to name extension of This_item
set FileName to name of This_item
set NameOnly to text 1 thru ((offset of Ext in FileName) - 2) of FileName -- get name without .extension
set name of This_item to (NameOnly & Sufix & "." & Ext) -- change the name of the file
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pbell, your code enlightened so much and I think you're almost solving the problem. I tried your code but I keep getting a loop where the external app opens a file (each time with a new "_edited" suffix attached to it). I believe the problem is that your code renames the source file but not the final processed file (inside the folder "Done", therefore the droplet understands a new file came into the main folder and keeps generating new files. It's silly but I can't even figure out how to change the name of each (that's the point) of the generated files... Any advice? Big thanks!

Comment: the difficulty I have to help you is that I don't know what your third party application does and how it does it. Power, if that application post the result in new files in "Done" folder, may be you could just use the rename instructions in a new folder action script defined for folder "Done" ?

Comment: Thanks @Pbell, you are right! The app just takes the files you drop, processes them and saves them with the same name and ext. to the "Done" folder.Hence that I want to change the ext. I thought about your approach but didn't succeed in automatizing the process with all the files dropped in the "done" folder. I tried with something like: `set fileN to item i of items in destination_path` to use "fileN" in your code instead of "This_item" but it didn't work... Would the rename instruction apply automatically to any file in the "Done" folder adding a suffix? Thnks & Sorry I'm so dumb!

Comment: in summary what you want to do: 1) drop file F.ext into folder A (path = "A/F.ext"). 2) it triggers a script which creates folder Done in folder A (path = "A/Done") and send file F.ext to an application. 3) this application processes that file and stores the result in folder Done with name F.ext (path = A/Done/F.ext). this last thing I am not clear is the suffix. I understand you want to change the "A/F.ext" to "A/F_edited.ext". then my question is  : how do you know that the application has processed it ? only because now you have A/Done/F.ext ? please confirm and we will find solution.

Comment: Pbell people like you "wasting" time for nothing with people like me are awesome. We need more of that in this world, thanks. You are so right, the external app edits the file and saves it to "A/Done/F.ext" (the same name than in "A/F.ext"). I know it's proccessed because it creates the file (the part of the code for the app works ok). So I don't want to add the suffix to "A/F.ext" but to "A/Done/F_edited.ext" (that way I have the original file with one name and the edited with the "edited" suffix in "A/Done/"). (Continues below...)

Comment: My biggest challenge is that what I drop to "A" is more than 1 file at the same time and I can't figure out how to apply properly a variable to the code so the change in all the names (adding suffix) of the files in "A/Done/" is automatic. Thanks a trillion again @pbell!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @pbell !... Your code worked perfectly after some trying. At first the code (for the first droplet, the one that processes the files) didn't work for me... It just didn't do anything. I decided then to change this part of your code:

```
repeat This_item in these_items times -- loop on each added item in parent folder
```

for this other:

```
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in these_items
    set this_item to item i of these_items -- loop on each added item in parent folder
```

To be honest, I don't know very well
1) Why I changed it.
2) Why it turned to work fine after the change.

You mentioned something about El Capitán and I'm still running Mavericks (I know...) so maybe it has something to do...

So then, after the change actually it didn't immediately start working, it was after a couple of tries dropping/deleting the files (in A/F.ext) when it started working perfectly. I have no idea why that happened, I guess it has something to do with the file system structure: I use Pathfinder and have hidden files enabled and noticed that it was after the hidden file ".DS_Store" appeared in both folders (A & Done) when everything started working fine.

So thanks again @pbell, you're a genius and now I learnt just a little more (still dumb though)... Soon I'll need to make another applescript to move specific files from different subfolders to a parent one and once there try to compress them all... that's my next challenge but I think it'll be a lot easier than this one :)
   I'm very grateful and I hope this helps other out there!...